# Cumulative sum of previous rows for each partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, lag, cumulative-sum

I want to calculate the cumulative sum of monthly orders for each customer in my database.

For example, I have this data:

| customer | year | month | no_orders |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1544 | 2022 | 4 | 5 |
| 1544 | 2022 | 4 | 1 |
| 1544 | 2022 | 12 | 1 |
| 1544 | 2023 | 1 | 3 |

And the result should be the same as below:

| customer | year | month | cumulative no_orders |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1544 | 2022 | 4 | 0 |
| 1544 | 2022 | 12 | 6 |
| 1544 | 2023 | 1 | 7 |

I used `lag()` and in the next step, `sum() over ()` but my result was false!

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Comment: Seems like you need to do several steps here. Aggregate (and group) into months first, and then use a cumulative `SUM` but have the window not include the current row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [@Larnu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/larnu) advises in the comments

> Seems like you need to do several steps here. Aggregate (and group)
> into months first, and then use a cumulative SUM but have the window
> not include the current row.

Some SQL to implement this idea is below ([DB FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/Fom5oJlo))

```
SELECT customer,
       year,
       month,
       cumulative_no_orders = ISNULL(SUM(SUM(no_orders))
                                       OVER (
                                         PARTITION BY customer
                                         ORDER BY year, month 
                                         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
                                     , 0)
FROM   YourTable
GROUP  BY customer,
          year,
          month
```

It first does the aggregation

```
SELECT customer,
       year,
       month,
       sum_no_orders = SUM(no_orders)
FROM   YourTable
GROUP  BY customer, year, month
```

to return the following

| customer | year | month | sum_no_orders |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1544 | 2022 | 4 | 6 |
| 1544 | 2022 | 12 | 1 |
| 1544 | 2023 | 1 | 3 |

and then calculates the running total of sum_no_orders from *previous* rows on top of that.

Comment: Thanks but if a date (for example 2023-1) has more than 2 rows in the database, in result I it has more than 1 row. I want just 1 row for each year-month in the result.

Comment: That is not the case. `GROUP  BY customer, year, month` will give you one row

Comment: `2022` `4` has 2 rows in your sample data, @WhoIsKi , and you can see in the results that only 1 row, for `2022` `4`, is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
SELECT
    customer
    , year
    , month
    , ISNULL(LAG(no_orders) OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY customer, year, month),0) Cum_Orders
FROM (
    SELECT
        DISTINCT customer, year, month
        , SUM(no_orders) OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY customer, year, month) no_orders 
    FROM ABC
) a
```

Comment: Why `DISTINCT` with a windowed aggregate and not just use a `GROUP BY`?